# iOS9 XCTest - how to use expectations to test asynchronous cases without blocks?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ios9, xctest, xctestexpectation

I'm looking at [this example of using asynchronous testing using iOS9 expectations](http://blog.dadabeatnik.com/2014/07/13/asynchronous-unit-testing-in-xcode-6/). It makes sense for network requests and other operations that have completion blocks which can fulfill expectation.

However, I'm attempting to unit test classes which do not use callback blocks. So far I found that the code below works some of the time, but I'm not sure if I'm using the correct approach.

**How do I delay a test case while the app has a chance to do something in background?** Can I use perform selector in this case to check something and fulfill expectation from that background thread before the timeout?

```
-(void)checkFoundExpectedSubview:(MockViewController*)mockViewController
{
    if(mockViewController.didFindExpectedSubview)
    {
        [self.expectation fulfill];
    }
}


-(void)testErrorMessage
{
    MockViewController* mockViewController = [MockViewController create];
    [mockViewController expectSubviewWithClass:@"TSMessageView"];

    NSString* title = @"Error!";
    NSString* subtitle = @"This is a unit test of an error message";

    [self.errorHandler reportErrorWithTitle:title message:subtitle];
//this checks and fulfills my expectation
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkFoundExpectedSubview:) withObject:mockViewController afterDelay:2];

    self.expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Waiting for the error to be presented"];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:3 handler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        XCTAssertNil(error);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CFRunLoopRunInMode()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopRunInMode) to wait for a certain amount of time, or until the condition is fulfilled.

```
time_t start = time(NULL);
while (![mockViewController checkFoundExpectedSubview] && time(NULL)-start < 5.0) {
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, NO);
}
XCTAssertTrue([mockViewController checkFoundExpectedSubview], "Expected something, didn't happen");
```

The above code will wait for until either `checkFoundExpectedSubview` returns true, or the 5 seconds allowed duration passes. Having the run loop running means the main thread (queue) is allowed to process events and blocks submitted to it.

The code can be sum up this into a nicely macro:

```
#define wait(timeout, condition, message) \
{ \
    time_t start = time(NULL); \
    while (!condition && time(NULL)-start < 5.0) { \
        CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, .1, NO); \
    } \
    XCTAssertTrue(condition, message); \
}
```

that can be used like this:

```
wait(5, [mockViewController checkFoundExpectedSubview], "Expected something, didn't happen");
```